# Downsides to using ProxyJump when not necessary

Tags: ssh, proxy

Are there any downsides to using `ProxyJump` when not necessary?

We use a shared .ssh/config file amongst many machines, some of which are behind a jumpbox and others are not. For two machines that are behind a particular jumpbox, is there a downside to still using the `ProxyJump` option? (I would guess there would be an imperceptible amount of additional latency but that is it).

Right now our shared config uses this setup to only use `ProxyJump` when needed:

```
Match Host example Exec "! nslookup $(nslookup internal.site.com | head -1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+\([.][0-9]\+\)\{3\}') | grep -o 'name = .\+site.com\.$'"
    ProxyJump jumpbox
Host example
    HostName example.internal.site.com
```

However, the `Match Exec` check is a bit fragile and won't necessarily work on all systems properly.

Comment: If you have less portable checks to do, run a well-behaved script in a well-behaved, explicitly specified shell (possibly not even using the ProxyJump shorthand, but manually specifying ProxyCommand like `if condition; then exec ssh -W "$1:$2" proxy; else nc "$1" "$2"; fi`)

Comment: Special cases to think about: Connecting to the local system (should usually use loopback, not proxy) and connecting to the proxy itself (deteriorates user experience if using two connections where one would suffice).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ProxyJump in essence does the following:

1. It connects to the *proxy*, creating a TCP port forward of random local port to the target port (22 or whichever is configured for target host). This connection lives in the background.
2. It then connects to this forwarded port, thereby using just created SSH TCP tunnel. The tunnel is set up to connect to target host SSH port, so the connection proceeds to that target port.

The SSH connection is therefore direct. You can pass TCP tunnels through it, forward or reverse, or use any other SSH features. You can even use a proxied server as a proxy to the third system, and then there will be two background connections forwarding random ports.

The downsides as I see them are:

- The dependence on the proxy. If you need to do some work on the proxy itself, reboot it, or something like this, all connections that are running through will be terminated.
- The target host sees connection as if it is done from the proxy. The real address of the connecting system is completely hidden. The burden of supporting the security of this lies on the proxy. More, if the target host has some auto-banning service running like fail2ban, and if the proxy connection was successful, but target is not, that service could eventually block any connections from proxy. Not very convenient!

Both of these downsides are the necessary trade-ofs of using proxy, but sometimes, when the host is accessible directly, could be unexpected (i.e. when you think you're connecting directly).

Comment: You brought up several circumstances I didn't remember even though they have been experienced before.